# Empty HTML mails in outlook.com, microsoft exchange & hotmail.com

Tags: html, css, wordpress, outlook, html-email

I have to style an email and when I was done and tested it all seemed to work fine, except in outlook.com, Microsoft exchange and Hotmail. For some reason exchange strips all code used (tables, tr & td tags) whatever I do, is there some workaround or is it just not possible? I have used CSS in my `<style>` tag. Should I change that to inline styling? or is there some other use.

Also my mail uses certain values (shortcodes) which are being given by the form, this works all fine in all other mail boxes but again not in outlook. If I can't use code there is there some workaround for that too?

So long story short, how can I use code in my html-email if Microsoft exchange breaks all code and gives a blank mail.
The entire mail you can see here on my [test site](http://wouterstage.eu/mail-style-stackoverflow/)

Here is my mail code:

```
<style> 
td {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #78797a;
    width: 420px;
    line-height: 22px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
img {
     display:block;
    }
    
h3  {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #434343;
    }
h4  {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #434343;
    }
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
</style>

<table style="font-size: 15px; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight: 200;">
<img src="http://www.belife.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/belife-RGB.jpg" align="top"><br>

<h4>Verwijzend arts</h4>
<tr style="padding: 10px">
  <td> Naam</td><td> [naam_vw]</td>
</tr>

<tr style="padding: 10px">
  <td> Voorletters</td> <td>[voorletters_vw]</td>
</tr>

<tr style="padding: 10px">
    <td> Geslacht</td> <td>[geslacht_vw]</td>
</tr>

<tr style="padding: 10px">
    <td> Functie verwijzer:</td> <td>[verwijzer_vw]</td>
</tr>

 <tr style="padding: 10px">
    <td> Naam instantie:</td> <td>[instantie_vw]</td>
</tr>

<tr style="padding: 10px">
    <td>Adres:</td> <td>[adres_vw]</td>
</tr>

<tr style="padding: 10px">
    <td>Postcode:</td> <td>[postcode_vw]</td>
</tr>

<tr style="padding: 10px">
    <td>AGB code verwijzer:</td> <td>[agb_vw]</td>
</tr>

<tr style="padding: 10px">
    <td>Mobiel verwijzer:</td> <td>[mobiel_vw]</td>
</tr>

<tr style="padding: 10px">
    <td>E-mail:</td> <td>[email_vw]</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Shortcodes such as [email_vw] are the ones that are being given via the form which need to be in there.

Any tips and answers are appreciated thanks in advance!

EDIT * I was able to fix outlook myself but now Hotmail is for some reason empty and shows just plain code, would this be caused by the code being inline? *

Comment: is the mail u send flaged as html mail? i know that in c# you when creating a mail u have to specifie if it is a html mail

Comment: Too little information! How do you send this email? Is this the complete sourcecode of the email? In that case largest part of HTML structure is missing. Shortcodes should be filled at create/send time, has nothing to do with outlook (or exchange). Please improve your question!

Comment: @IvanSanderdeJong It's not flagged like that I think, it does not say so in the other mail boxes where can I check?

Comment: @tvgemert apologies for the lack of information, the mail is send via a plugin in wordpress called contact form 7 (Should I move my question to there?) 

the submit structure is already live at [link]http://www.belife.nl/verwijzers/verwijsformulier/ (note dutch site)
My question is if this code works in outlook and if not what should be changed to make it work in outlook/exchange

Comment: It would definitely be good to tag [wordpress] in this question.

Comment: In general, if you add the rest of the HTML structure `<html><head><body>` etc (make it valid HTML). you should be able to receive it as HTML email in any email client (not taking into account all the specific quirks of email clients)

Comment: And of course your "wordpress plugin" is also involved in all this, meaning that you can also check specific issues around this plugin.

Comment: There is a lot of information about HTML email online, for instance: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/series/mastering-html-email--webdesign-17696 gives some good information to start with.

Comment: I've added the `<html><head><body>` tags and checked my plugin if I use normal text it just displays that so it must be outlook and the code. I'll read through that artical thanks in advance @tvgemert for all the help (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after some searching and reading @tvgemert's article link I was able to fix outlook.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <table style="font-size: 15px; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight: 200;">
<img src="http://www.belife.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/belife-RGB.jpg" align="top" style="display: block;"><br><h3 style="text-decoration: none; color: #434343;">Met deze brief verwijs ik onderstaande client naar u voor een programma medische specialistische revalidatiezorg (MSR) bij BeLife.</h3>

    <h4 style="text-decoration: none; color: #434343;">Verwijzend arts</h4>
    <tr style="padding: 10px;">
<td style="text-decoration: none; color: #78797a; width: 420px; line-height: 22px; border: 1px solid black;"> Naam</td>
<td style="text-decoration: none; color: #78797a; width: 420px; line-height: 22px; border: 1px solid black;"> [naam_vw]</td>
    </tr>
<tr style="padding: 10px;">
<td style="text-decoration: none; color: #78797a; width: 420px; line-height: 22px; border: 1px solid black;"> Voorletters</td> <td style="text-decoration: none; color: #78797a; width: 420px; line-height: 22px; border: 1px solid black;">[voorletters_vw]</td>
    </tr>
<tr style="padding: 10px;">
<td style="text-decoration: none; color: #78797a; width: 420px; line-height: 22px; border: 1px solid black;"> Geslacht</td> <td style="text-decoration: none; color: #78797a; width: 420px; line-height: 22px; border: 1px solid black;">[geslacht_vw]</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This has fixed outlook at the least by adding inline code the email is now no longer blank.